# canvas drawImage and scope issue

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm writing a small javascript class that I'm trying to use to create an image via canvas

I keep running into an issue where when I run the update function to redraw the canvas, some properties are undefined when they should be an instance of an image

To better explain what I mean, this code is what I have:

```
this.setHabboLeft = function(src)
{
    var callback = this.update;
    this.habboLeft = getImage(src, callback);
}

var getImage = function(src, callback)
{
    var img = new Image;

    if(typeof callback == 'function')
    {
        img.onload = callback;

    }

    img.src = src;
    return img;
}

this.update = function()
{   
    console.log('updating...', this.background, this.habboLeft);
    ...
}
```

I am using `setHabboLeft` that sets an image from an external URL, then once that is loaded, it will run `this.update()`

I think the problem is with the onload callback in getImage. The console.log should return the image object but tells me it's undefined

EDIT for @gus27

Note, the image is on a different domain

I call the functions like:

```
        // set background of lovelock
        lovelockCanvas.setBackground($(self).data('picture'));

        // create logged in user habbo
        var habboUrl = habboCreator.generateUrl({
            habbo_username: '{{ Auth::user()->habbo_username }}'
        });
        lovelockCanvas.setHabboLeft(habboUrl);
```

**EDIT 2**

Function being called
http://pastebin.com/ZRut9gyD

full js class
http://pastebin.com/WjRUkj4X

**FIXED:**

Instead of my update using `this` to draw everything, I created a new function and passed `this` as a parameter

See pastebin: http://pastebin.com/BTNigqLS

Comment: Are you loading the images from the same domain? Otherwise that could be the problem, for security reasons you can't put external images into the canvas.

Comment: Why do you use `this` in the definition of `this.setHabboLeft`? And please show how you call `setHabboLeft`?

Comment: @JonasGiuro No, the image is being loaded on an external domain.

Comment: And you have no "Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." error in the console?

Comment: IMHO it seems to be a classic `this` problem. But I'd like to see how the `lovelockCanvas` variable is instantiated and how the corresponding class/function is declared.

Comment: You can also bind any object to the function's `this` value. So your example could just do `this.habboLeft = getImage(src, callback.bind(this));` and that particular referance to the callback will always have `this` as the whatever you set it as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `update` function which is called by the `img`. When `update` is called by the `img` (by it's `onload` callback) the `this` variable in the `update` function refers to the `img`.

The [documentation for `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) states:

> Inside a function, the value of `this` depends on how the function is
>   called.

You can try something like that:

```
  this.setHabboLeft = function(src)
  {
      var callback = this.update;
      this.habboLeft = getImage(src, callback, this);
  }

  var getImage = function(src, callback, obj)
  {
      var img = new Image;
      if(typeof callback == 'function')
      {
          img.onload = function(){
            callback(obj);
          };
      }
      img.src = src;
      return img;
  }

  this.update = function(obj)
  {   
      console.log(this); // this is here the img, not the lovelockCanvas
      console.log('updating...', obj.background, obj.habboLeft);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

### Function.bind(objRef)

All functions are a type of object called Function [MDN Function object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). They come with some methods and properties, one of which is called bind.

Bind creates a new copy of the function binding its keyword (this) to the function.

Thus to solve the problem of an event overwriting the functions binding you simple do the binding yourself to ensure it is not overwritten by the native event handler.

```
this.setHabboLeft = function(src){
    // create a new function bound to this
    this.habboLeft = getImage(src, this.update.bind(this));
}

var getImage = function(src, callback){
    var img = new Image;    
    img.onload = typeof callback == 'function' ? callback : undefined;    
    img.src = src;
    return img;
}

this.update = function() {   
    console.log('updating...', this.background, this.habboLeft);
    ...
}
```

Additionally you don't have or add more intermediate steps to keep hold of the event object.

```
this.setHabboLeft = function(src){
    // create a new update function bound to this
    // only reference the image if it loads
    getImage(src, this.update.bind(this));
}

var getImage = function(src, callback){
    var img = new Image;    
    img.onload = typeof callback == 'function' ? callback : undefined;    
    img.src = src;
}

this.update = function(event){
    // image loaded so can be referenced
    this.habboLeft = event.target; // the image object
}
```